# Get 'many' objects in one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I created my classes and inserted some data into them on Parse.com using a browser. Basically, I created classes A and B. A has a column of type B.

Now I want to display that data in my app. I am using the following code to get class A which is working fine.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className:"A")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Do stuff
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

However, I am not able to get class B data. I tried the following

```
query.includeKey("B")
```

This throws an error saying this is not a pointer relationship.

I also tried

```
let bObjects = aObject.objectForKey("B") as? [PFObject]
```

But the result is nil.

Question: How do I get 'many' objects in a one-to-many relationship in Parse?

Comment: have you tried printing objects to see it's description or printing objects[0]?

Comment: What is the actual column name and type in your A class?  Is it "B" with type pointer?

Comment: In "A", I added a column of type Relation and Target Class "B" and named the column itself  "B".

Comment: @beyowulf bObjects is nil. It has no description and attempting to access bObjects[0] causes a crash

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. print(objects) or print(objects[0]) in your competition block.

Comment: @JonSetting If you're using relations, you should be using `relationForKey`

Comment: @lightice11 Of course! I just had to get the relation then execute its query. Could you please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using relations, you should be using `relationForKey`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented the accepted answer:

```
let bObjectsRelation = self.relationForKey("B")
bObjectsRelation.query()?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
       let bObjects = objects! as [PFObject]
    } else {
       print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```